# Java Runtime.exec() not returning PowerShell command output

Tags: java, powershell

I'm using Java to invoke a PowerShell command and then capturing the output.

I've run into an issue where one simple PowerShell command will return output, but another won't and I'm trying to understand why.

**This is the logic** (updated to include a check of the error output stream)

```
public class Example {

  private void myMethod(String command) throws IOException {
       Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
       BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

       String output = "";
       String line;
       while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        output += (line + "\n");
       }

       System.out.println((output.isEmpty() ? "No output was received!!!" : output));

       // Also iterate through the error stream to see if it caught anything.
       BufferedReader errorBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
       String errorOutput = "";
       while((line = errorBufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        errorOutput += (line + "\n");
       }

       System.out.println((errorOutput.isEmpty() ? "Nothing in the error output stream." : errorOutput));
  }


   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       new Example().myMethod("powershell -Command \"$PSVersionTable\"");
       new Example().myMethod("powershell -Command \"Get-Module -Name VMware* -ListAvailable\"");
   }
}
```

**This is the output**

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                   
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                   
PSVersion                      5.0.10586.117                                                                                                                                                           
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                                 
BuildVersion                   10.0.10586.117                                                                                                                                                          
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18444                                                                                                                                                         
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                     
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                                     
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                                                                                                 

Nothing in the error output stream.
No output was received!!!
Nothing in the error output stream.
```

So the 1st command being executed in `Main()` returns output, but the 2nd one doesn't and I don't understand why.

I can run the 2nd command manually through command prompt and it definitely works.

Any ideas on why I can't retrieve the output of the 2nd command when I'm programmatically executing it?

**Update**

When manually running the 2nd command, this is the output that gets generated.(and what I would expect my Java code to be capturing)

```
U:\>powershell -Command "Get-Module -Name VMware* -ListAvailable"


Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Binary     6.5.1.6... VMware.DeployAutomation             {Add-DeployRule, Add-ProxyServer, Add-ScriptBundle, Copy-DeployRule...}
Binary     6.5.1.6... VMware.ImageBuilder                 {Add-EsxSoftwareDepot, Add-EsxSoftwarePackage, Compare-EsxImageProfile, Export-EsxImageProfile...}
Manifest   6.5.4.7... VMware.PowerCLI
Binary     6.5.4.6... VMware.VimAutomation.Cis.Core       {Connect-CisServer, Disconnect-CisServer, Get-CisService}
Binary     6.5.1.5... VMware.VimAutomation.Cloud          {Add-CIDatastore, Connect-CIServer, Disconnect-CIServer, Get-Catalog...}
Manifest   6.5.4.6... VMware.VimAutomation.Common
Binary     6.5.2.6... VMware.VimAutomation.Core           {Add-PassthroughDevice, Add-VirtualSwitchPhysicalNetworkAdapter, Add-VMHost, Add-VMHostNtpServer...}
Binary     6.5.4.7... VMware.VimAutomation.HA             Get-DrmInfo
Binary     7.1.0.5... VMware.VimAutomation.HorizonView    {Connect-HVServer, Disconnect-HVServer}
Binary     6.5.1.5... VMware.VimAutomation.License        Get-LicenseDataManager
Binary     2.0.0.6... VMware.VimAutomation.Nsxt           {Connect-NsxtServer, Disconnect-NsxtServer, Get-NsxtService}
Binary     6.5.1.5... VMware.VimAutomation.PCloud         {Connect-PIServer, Disconnect-PIServer, Get-PIComputeInstance, Get-PIDatacenter}
Manifest   1.0.0.5... VMware.VimAutomation.Sdk            {Get-PSVersion, Get-InstallPath}
Binary     6.5.1.5... VMware.VimAutomation.Srm            {Connect-SrmServer, Disconnect-SrmServer}
Binary     6.5.4.7... VMware.VimAutomation.Storage        {Add-KeyManagementServer, Copy-VDisk, Export-SpbmStoragePolicy, Get-KeyManagementServer...}
Script     1.1        VMware.VimAutomation.StorageUtility Update-VmfsDatastore
Binary     6.5.1.5... VMware.VimAutomation.Vds            {Add-VDSwitchPhysicalNetworkAdapter, Add-VDSwitchVMHost, Export-VDPortGroup, Export-VDSwitch...}
Binary     6.5.4.7... VMware.VimAutomation.Vmc            {Connect-Vmc, Disconnect-Vmc, Get-VmcService, Connect-VmcServer...}
Binary     6.5.1.5... VMware.VimAutomation.vROps          {Connect-OMServer, Disconnect-OMServer, Get-OMAlert, Get-OMAlertDefinition...}
Binary     6.5.1.5... VMware.VumAutomation                {Add-EntityBaseline, Copy-Patch, Get-Baseline, Get-Compliance...}
```

Comment: Maybe your 2nd command outputs in error stream, and as I can read from your code, you aren't reading anything from error stream. You can add it by: `BufferedReader bufferedReaderErrorStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));`

Comment: @t6nand I had come across another post where someone mentioned the same thing.  So I also captured the error stream and attempted to iterate through it, but it also returns no output.

Comment: What actually outputs the second command to the PowerShell console?

Comment: could it be some typo on your command in -Name parameter? try changing the value and see if it is the same result

Comment: @briarheart I just updated the post to include the output that gets generated when I run the command manually via "cmd".

Comment: @johnll I updated the post with the output I get when I manually run the 2nd command via "cmd".  Unless I'm totally overlooking something, those commands appear to be the exact same (except for the Java escaping of special characters)

Comment: Silly question perhaps: do you get the same behaviour if you replace `VMware*` with `Win*`?  I don't have VMware on my machine and I can't reproduce your problem with `Win*`.

Comment: @LukeWoodward I so I just ran `new Example().myMethod("powershell -Command \"Get-Module -Name Win* -ListAvailable\"");` and I'm still getting the same behavior.  (no output and no error output)

Also, running the command manually via "cmd" also returns no output.  `powershell -Command "Get-Module -Name Win* -ListAvailable"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what was going on here.

Quick recap of the problem ::

- I had manually installed some VMWare modules via the PowerShell gallery.
- I was attempting to programmatically retrieve a list of all of the available VMware modules that I had installed.
- I was getting no standard output or error output.

Reason this was happening ::

- I had installed the VMWare modules via a 64-bit Powershell.
- My Java program was running against a 32-bit JDK.
- So when Java opened a cmd prompt, it was opening the 32-bit cmd prompt, which in-turn invoked the 32-bit Powershell.
- I didn't install the VMWare modules for the 32-bit Powershell and that's why I wasn't getting any output when I tried to programmatically retrieve a list of all of the available VMWare modules.
- When I was manually running the command to retrieve a list of all of the Available VMWare modules, I was using the 64-bit Powershell (which I had installed the VMWare modules for)

Once I installed the VMware modules via the 32-bit Powershell, then my Java program (which runs in a 32-bit context) began working as expected.